# Django Formset: Is there any chance to add missing field content in the post() method of a CreateView?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've created a `CreateView` with a `modelformset`, added some js to add or remove additional forms. It is a view to create a booking from a bank booking entry. And as the 'from_account' is obvious (the booking is launched from a certain bank booking entry and handing over the pk from the bank booking in the url), I do not want to show this (selection-) field in the form. So I put the field as a hidden field in the formset with the objective to fill it in the post.
All this works as expected until submit.

Now, in the post() method, I see in formset.error correctly the errors for the missing fields 'bank_account_ta' and 'from_account'. Since I don't know the total_forms number (it might have been changed using js), I cannot prefill it while instantiating the formset class.

Working around in the template with js is possible, but not the proper way...

I would rather using the formset.clean() method but whatever I try, the formset.error remains as before which leads to `not formset.is_valid()`.

My questions: What is the easiest way to complete data (cleaned_data) of a formset in post()? Another point which is still hurting me: Is it necessary or helpful to define `self.object` in a formset and if yes, how? I put it to None as I receive a missing object error if I leave it undefined.

Thank you in advance.

views.py

```
class TransactionMulitCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Transaction
template_name = 'accounting/transaction_formset.html'
extra_context = {'title': model._meta.verbose_name, }
success_url = reverse_lazy('finance:ta_groups')
TaFormset = modelformset_factory(Transaction,
                                 formset=TransactionBaseFormset,
                                 exclude=('validity_period_start', 'validity_period_end', 'ta_group'),
                                 extra=1)


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    ba = BankTransaction.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['bank_ta_pk'])
    form = self.TaFormset(queryset=Transaction.objects.none(), initial=[
        {
            # commented out, as it was the js approach.
            # 'bank_account_ta': ba,
            # 'from_account': ba.account.ca_account,
            'posting_text': ba.booking_string(),
            'valuta': ba.valuta,
            'entry_date': ba.entry_date,
            'value': ba.amount,
        },
    ], ba=ba)
    helper = TransactionMultiFormsetHelper()
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, helper=helper, bank_ta=ba))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    ba = BankTransaction.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['bank_ta_pk'])
    # pass in initial to be able to detect changes, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/
    formset = self.TaFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, initial=[
        {
            # commented out, as it was the js approach.
            # 'bank_account_ta': ba,
            # 'from_account': ba.account.ca_account,
            'posting_text': ba.booking_string(),
            'valuta': ba.valuta,
            'entry_date': ba.entry_date,
            'value': ba.amount,
        },
    ], ba=ba)

    formset.clean()
    # formset = self.TaFormset()
    if formset.is_valid():
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        split = TransactionGroup.objects.create(create_by=self.request.user, update_by=self.request.user)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.ta_group = split
            instance.save()
        # BankTransaction.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['bank_ta_pk']).update(is_booked=True)
        ba.is_booked = True
        ba.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('finance:bank_tas'))
        # return self.form_valid(formset)
    else:
        helper = TransactionMultiFormsetHelper()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=formset, helper=helper, bank_ta=ba))
        # return self.form_invalid(formset)
```

forms.py

```
class TransactionBaseFormset(forms.BaseModelFormSet):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # self.ba_pk = kwargs.pop('ba_pk')
    try:
        self.ba = kwargs.pop('ba')
    except KeyError:
        self.ba = None
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean(self):
    data = None
    for form in self.forms:
        data = form.cleaned_data
        data['bank_account_ta'] = self.ba
        data['from_account'] = self.ba.account.ca_account
    return data
```

Comment: There was some rubbish in there: calling `formset.clean()` is called in `formset.is_valid()` anyway. To call it separately leads to an error when raising a `ValidationError`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
The simple solution is to exclude all enforced fields and fill them either in the `clean()` or in the `is_valid()` function.

```
TaFormset = modelformset_factory(Transaction,
                                 formset=TransactionBaseFormset,
                                 exclude=(
                                     'validity_period_start',
                                     'validity_period_end',
                                     'ta_group',
                                     'bank_account_ta',
                                     'from_account',
                                 ),
                                 extra=1)
```

However, I would still like to know which role plays (or might play) `self.object` in a formset (or modelformset)?